# What flower is this? (Dolomites, Italy)

Tags: species-identification, flowers

I took this picture a few days ago in Val Rendena, in the dolomitic [Brenta group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brenta_group) (2000 m). The whole plant was 15 cm tall at most, and it had a single leaf on the stem. What flower is it?

[image]

Comment: How was the leaf ? (Shape, texture...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a look at white-flowered plants flowering in July in a site about the flora of the French Alps, and the best I could find was *Parnassia palustris*:
http://www.florealpes.com/fiche_parnassie.php

[image: Parnassia palustris]

At this developmental stage, it looks quite similar to your photo, with the same kind of structures at the base of the petals.
The site says that there are heart-shaped leaves at the base, plus one on the stem. This last leaf matches your description. The site says it can grow up to 2500m.

The [Italian Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parnassia_palustris) says:

> In Italia è presente solo nelle regioni settentrionali e centrali, nonché in Campania.[2] In montagna si spinge fino a circa 2000 m, ma sulle Alpi è stata segnalata anche a quote superiori (3000 m sul versante svizzero del Monte Rosa).

This means that it can be found in the Italian Alps too, including at 2000m.